# Good location to store .py files on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I've written some python modules that I'd like to be able to import anytime on Mac OS X.  I've done some googling and I've gotten some mixed responses so I'd like to know what the "best" practice is for storing those files safely.

I'm running Python2.7 and I want to make sure I don't mess with the Mac install of Python or anything like that.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @mata not a duplicate as the answer I gave for OSX does not match the answer given in the other question

Comment: @Mark Your answer should be added to the original question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard directory which is already searched by python depends on the version of python.

For the Apple installed python 2.7 it is `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

the README in that directory says

> This directory exists so that 3rd party packages can be installed
>   here.  Read the source for site.py for more details.